# Angularjs ui router needs to load child state by default similar to home page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I am using angularjs ui router  and I need to load the child state by default (i.e., 'dashboardParent.dashboard').

```
$stateProvider.state('dashboardParent', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/dashboard/dashboard-parent.html',
        controller: 'DashboardParentController'
    }).state('dashboardParent.dashboard', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/dashboard/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'DashboardController'
    })
```

Generally what we do is we have `home` state with url ("/") from there we navigate to some other state let say  `'dashboardParent.dashboard'`. But here I don't have any `home` state. When I start the application I want `dashboardParent.dashboard` state to be loaded. How to achieve it.

If I add another state `home` and provide a link to navigate to  the state `'dashboardParent.dashboard'` it is loading fine. But my requirement is I do not have any home state, instead I need to load `'dashboardParent.dashboard'` by default. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

code below will help you:

```
// if the path doesn't match any of the urls you configured
// otherwise will take care of routing the user to the specified url
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

reference: [URL-Routing of ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#otherwise-for-invalid-routes)

note: Don't forget injecting the `$urlRouterProvider` service.